# float image left as background - css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this html:

```
<style>
#todo{
display:table;
border:1px solid #000;
}

.divimg{
float: left; 
height: 100px; 
margin-right: 0px; 
margin-bottom: 0px;
}
</style>

<div id=todo>
<img class=divimg src=https://40.media.tumblr.com/2292c0583894cd27ef887ca431e4cc40/tumblr_mkjw8oi7vb1s5jt7zo1_500.jpg></img>
<img class=divimg src=http://36.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m6pvhwHP2O1rp9ko0o1_500.jpg></img>
<img class=divimg src=http://data.whicdn.com/images/48891103/tumblr_mghlgh66It1r0i9t4o1_500_large.png></img>
<img class=divimg src=http://www.ladylaike.com.br/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/beach-summer-tumblr.jpg></img>
<img class=divimg src=https://41.media.tumblr.com/bdc50942adb5463db541bc77fcecede2/tumblr_n5mkb0CXlV1s7s4cuo2_500.jpg></img>
<img class=divimg src=https://40.media.tumblr.com/2292c0583894cd27ef887ca431e4cc40/tumblr_mkjw8oi7vb1s5jt7zo1_500.jpg></img>
<img class=divimg src=http://36.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m6pvhwHP2O1rp9ko0o1_500.jpg></img>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v5wj21c5/

my problem is, I want the same result as I have in this, but with images in background, not as img tag. Is it possible? how can i do that?

Comment: use the css `background-image` on the ids you want them to be background for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can add multiple-image on background with floating attribute.

But you can create 2 div with `position:absolute` CSS attribute. The background div with `z-index:1;` and the content div with `z-index:2`

Like that : https://jsfiddle.net/qxo8q2hn/2/

Answer (score 0):

Use a div tag instead of an img tag. Change the display to inline-block and control their size with background-size.

```
<div id=todo>
    <div class='div-img1 divimg'></div>
    <div class='div-img1 divimg'></div>
    <div class='div-img1 divimg'></div>
    <div class='div-img1 divimg'></div>
    <div class='div-img2 divimg'></div>
</div>
```

...

```
<style>
#todo{


border:1px solid #000;
}

.divimg{
display:inline-block;
height: 100px; 
width:100px;
background-size:100px 100px;
margin-right: 0px; 
margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.div-img1 {
    background-image:url('https://40.media.tumblr.com/2292c0583894cd27ef887ca431e4cc40/tumblr_mkjw8oi7vb1s5jt7zo1_500.jpg');
}

.div-img2 {
    background-image:url('http://36.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m6pvhwHP2O1rp9ko0o1_500.jpg');
}

</style>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v5wj21c5/22/

Comment: thank you. but in this example I can't have images with different width... and I want they have same height, but not width. I think with background I cant have this, can i?

Answer (score 0):

Since you know how wide you want the images you could do multiple background images and just set the distance, but you'd have to give the div some height and width otherwise it will just collapse

```
div {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background-image: url(“https://40.media.tumblr.com/2292c0583894cd27ef887ca431e4cc40/tumblr_mkjw8oi7vb1s5jt7zo1_500.jpg”), url(“http://36.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m6pvhwHP2O1rp9ko0o1_500.jpg”), url(“http://data.whicdn.com/images/48891103/tumblr_mghlgh66It1r0i9t4o1_500_large.png”);
    background-size: 100px auto, 100px auto, 100px auto;
    background-position: 0 0, 100px 0, 200px 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;    
}
```

here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v5wj21c5/27/)

Comment: But you set the position of all background image manually here, it's not floating

Comment: True! No floating. It's really only a partial solution because of that, but since she seems to want them all the same width it should be pretty easy to accomplish. It's almost like a reverse sprite.

Comment: yeah! i want something more dinamic, because I will have different images that PHP will bring and each image has different height and width.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple background images as a css-property with `background-image:url(...), url(...), ...`.

Example HTML:

```
<div id="todo">
    Example Text.
    Example Text.
    Example Text.
    Example Text.
</div>
```

With CSS (3 of your images):

```
#todo {
    margin:5px;
    padding:50px 0px 0px 0px;
    border:1px solid black;
    height:500px; 
    width:1000px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-image:url("https://40.media.tumblr.com/2292c0583894cd27ef887ca431e4cc40/tumblr_mkjw8oi7vb1s5jt7zo1_500.jpg"),
        url("http://36.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m6pvhwHP2O1rp9ko0o1_500.jpg"),
        url("http://data.whicdn.com/images/48891103/tumblr_mghlgh66It1r0i9t4o1_500_large.png");
    background-size:50px 50px;
    background-position:0px 0px, 50px 0px, 100px 0px;
}
```

See altered [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/verufv7L/) for the result. Works in Chrome and Firefox for me.

Comment: But you set the position of all background image manually here, it's not floating

Comment: thank you. but in this example I can't have images with different width... and I want they have same height, but not width. I think with background I cant have this, can i?

Comment: You can have different widths by adjusting background-size and background-position for each image, see https://jsfiddle.net/snot0c1q/ (first image width: 50px, second: 100px, third: 400px)

Comment: yeah! i want something more dinamic, because I will have different images that PHP will bring and each image has different height and width.